# What does Hanami mean by the words, "Die and become a sage"?

Tags: japanese-language, culture, jujutsu-kaisen

In *Jujutsu Kaisen*'s episode 18 "Sage" (Transcription: "Kenja"; Japanese: 賢者), Hanami disrupts the Goodwill Event and engages Fushiguro Megumi, Inumaki Toge and Kamo Noritoshi in combat. But, just before that, she elaborates on her outlook by saying the following:

> The forest, ocean, and sky… They cry out in pain, saying they can't bear it anymore. They can no longer coexist with humans. They know that some humans are kind to this planet, but how much can that kindness make up for?
>
> All they want is time. If there's enough time, this planet can shine again. A time without humans.
>
> Die, and become a sage.

What exactly does Hanami mean by the last line, "Die, and become a sage"? It is clear that Hanami envisions a future for the planet when there are no more humans, but what does it mean to become a sage by dying? Is something being lost in translation, here?

I notice that the episode is titled "Sage", and that Hanami uses the word "Kenja" in this line. Is there some subtlety in the meaning of the word "Kenja" that is not being conveyed accurately through the English word "sage"? Or, is there some cultural notion of "dying and becoming a sage" that I should be aware of in order to understand the import of this line?

Comment: There are Japanese account of master sages who manage to transcend their material form and so cease to become human.  This may contain an allusion:  to be so wise as to die would allow you to transcend.

Comment: @Mary that’s an interesting perspective. Would love to see a detailed analysis, if possible :)